# What happens in a tie on Only Connect?

Tags: only-connect

In the game show, Only Connect, it's entirely possible that both teams end up with the same score.  (Episode 4x07 came dangerously close to this, prompting this question)

I've tried to look around for the official rules for Only Connect, but I can't seem to find any.

What is the tiebreaker for Only Connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened a few times - they do an extra missing vowels question for the team captains only. The rule is mentioned on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect#Round_4:_Missing_Vowels) for the show:

> If teams are tied, then a single sudden-death puzzle is given to the captains of each team. If a captain buzzes in first and gives the correct answer then their team wins, but an incorrect answer automatically forfeits the game. Although no category is officially given they make reference to their own role as sudden-death questions. Examples are "So Long and Thanks for All the Fish", "To the Victor, the Spoils" and "Winner Stays On".